# I need to open a file with pandas but name includes \a

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to open a file using the next code:

```
import pandas as pd

xls = pd.ExcelFile('Ligas_csv\all_euro_data_2000-2001.xls')
```

but I get the next message:

```
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'Ligas_csv\x07ll_euro_data_2000-2001.xls'
```

I've noticed \a is printed with a different color in my studio, so I guess it must be an special character, but I cant figure out to write that without causing this error.

:(

Comment: Pick one: 1) use a forward slash instead of a backslash 2) escape the backslash with another backslash 3) turn the path string into a raw string by using the ``r`` prefix

Comment: You need to escape the backslash. Use `Ligas_csv\\all_euro_data_2000-2001.xls` (double backslash)

Answer (score 2):

There are two possible ways to fix this:

1. replace the `\a` with `\\a` (escape the backslash with another backslash).
2. add `r` in front of the string (make it a raw string).